# During protractor tests navigating away from the page and then returning breaks waitForAngularEnabled()

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular8

While running e2e tests against an angular 8 application, the test driver fails if I navigate away from the application and return to it within the test.

More specifically:

In my Angular 8 application, I have a set of protractor e2e tests that require authentication to a server at an external page.

In protractor's onPrepare function, I begin a test run by waiting for the application to detect that authentication is needed and redirect to the login page, which is not itself an angular app.

I then call waitForAngularEnabled(false), perform the necessary steps to login, and re-enable waitForAngular.

The code looks like this:

```
const onPrepare = async () => {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

  await browser.get('/');
  await $('#username').clear();
  await $('#username').sendKeys('username');
  await $('#password').clear();
  await $('#password').sendKeys('password');
  await $('button[value=login]').click();

  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
}
```

After resuming the tests, any operation that waits for a UI element times out indefinitely.  The stack trace shows a failure at `waitForAngular`.

If I leave waiting for angular toggled off by skipping that last call to `waitForAngularEnabled(true)`, tests run mostly normally, but lots of operations suddenly need extra manual `wait` calls for that to work.

Is there a way to restore the original `waitForAngular` behavior once I've returned to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the `await`'s for the `waitForAngularEnabled` method.

```
const onPrepare = async () => {
  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

  await browser.get('/');
  await $('#username').clear();
  await $('#username').sendKeys('username');
  await $('#password').clear();
  await $('#password').sendKeys('password');
  await $('button[value=login]').click();

  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: right, and you may need to wait until the page if fully loaded, before ` browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);`